# How to export/save edited samples from Reason's NN-XT?

Tags: sample, sampler, export, reason

I edit samples in the NN-XT sampler of Reason like mod envelopes, pitch etc. After that I would like to export or save the playback of one key/note as Wave file. For example I have a monkey scream on C1, D1 and E1. Now I want a wave file for every note. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no "direct" way to export a sample built from reason synths/samplers. What you can do is:

- Set your reason project to only play the single note you want to export (clear the sequencer and only leave a single note) and use the "Export as WAV feature". Reproduce for each note.
- The other way around is to use signal routing on your workstation to feed the sample to a DAW or audio editor. Eg. you can use Rewire to feed Reason's audio to a track in Ableton Live, press record in Live, and play the desired note in reason. Use an editor to trim silences. Or use ASIO routing if your card supports it to feed the audio to an editor (Soundforge, Audacity...)